# Overriding CustomerData/Cart.php removes Total from MiniCart Magento 2

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, overriding, customer-data

I have overridden

> \vendor\magento\module-checkout\CustomerData\Cart.php

file in my custom plugin using di.xml using below code:

```
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart"
                 type="Vendor\Package\CustomerData\Cart" />
```

It's working too. I can get SectionData defined in my custom Cart.php file in Minicart successfully.

but this removes Total from my Minicart which was working fine with default Cart.php.

Please suggest if i am doing something wrong in overriding file.

[image: Reference image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by following method:

**File: di.xml**

```
 <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart">
      <plugin name="CustomMiniCart" type="Vendor\Package\CustomerData\Cart" sortOrder="1"/>
 </type>
```

**File:Vendor\Package\CustomerData\Cart.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Package\CustomerData;
class Cart
{
    public function afterGetSectionData(\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart $subject, $result)
    {

        $result['customdata1'] = $customvalue1;
        $result['customdata2'] =  $customvalue2;
        return $result;
    }  
}
```